# Opening tweet on iPhone leads to 404

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I am working on an iPhone app where I am linking to specific Twitter tweets in the native Twitter app. I attempt to open the twitter app like this:

```
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"twitter://status?status_id=%i", [self.tweetID intValue] ];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSLog(@"Opening Twitter: %@", stringURL);
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

But after the app opens it says "Error loading tweets (404)". I verified that I am using the same scheme as the twitter website (There is a button in the top right which will open a tweet in the iPhone twitter app). Clicking the link from the twitter website works fine, so it is some problem with how I do the link in my app.

All I can think is that the issue happens because I am in debug mode on my iPhone and my app isn't released yet or something...but that seems very strange. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using intValue is probably truncating the tweetID.  Try this instead for making your stringURL (assuming self.tweetID is an NSString).

```
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"twitter://status?status_id=%@", self.tweetID];
```

Answer (score 0):

Twitter displays an Error 404 message when a user has tried to retrieve their Twitter stream too many times in a limited amount of time. This is called rate limiting.

The URI requested is invalid or the resource requested, such as a user, does not exists etc.

If you want to just open twitter app using your application then try following code.This code works in every condition either you are logged out or logged in to twitter.

```
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"twitter://connect?status_id=%i",[self.tweetID intValue]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSLog(@"Opening Twitter: %@", stringURL);
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 0):

twitter posting....check it out

```
   if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {


 SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                             composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

        [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Great fun to learn iOS programming at appcoda.com!"];

        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: This will open twitter post dialog not twitter application installed in your device.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.
It is a great tutorial to integrate FB or/and Twitter and publish a post/tweet with native FB/Twitter app.

```
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-integrate-twitter-and-facebook-sharing-in-ios-6/
```